# Move some columns from a row into a new row

Tags: sas

I have already read some approaches into this issue but until now could not deliver any results on my own, probably because i‘am new in this tool, so beg for some help :)

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide 8.1.

Have:

```
DATE     |COD|TOTAL |P1_DX    |P1_DY    |P1_CD|P2_DX    |P2_DY    |P2_CD| ...until P8_
01JAN2004|9  |185   |02FEB2005|27SEP2010|36   |10SEP2011|12DEC2020|16   |  
31JAN2010|2  |351   |17FEB2015|27DEC2020|2    |         |         |     |  
(...)
```

Want

```
DATE      |COD|TOTAL |DX       |DY       |CD |
01JAN2004 |9  |185   |02FEB2005|27SEP2010|36 |
01JAN2004 |9  |185   |10SEP2011|12DEC2020|16 |
31JAN2010 |2  |351   |17FEB2015|27DEC2020|2  |
(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pivoting (also known as transposing) the data in multiple sets of columns.

Coders typically use `PROC TRANSPOSE` to pivot data, but the specifics of this question can't be handled in a single proc step.

Rather than doing steps TRANSPOSE/DATA/TRANSPOSE or TRANSPOSE/TRANSPOSE/TRANSPOSE/MERGE, a single DATA step with ARRAYs can be coded to perform the pivot.

Example:

NOTE: Your column naming convention `P<#>_DX`, `P<#>_DY`, and `P<#>_CD` means that the elements of the ARRAY must be explicitly listed.  If the column names instead were constructed using convention `DX_<#>` the columns could be specified in numbered suffix name list syntax `DX_1-DX_8`

```
data want;
  set have;
  array DXs(8) P1_DX P2_DX ...you fill in the rest... P8_DX;
  array DYs(8) P1_DY P2_DY ...you fill in the rest... P8_DY;
  array CDs(8) P1_CD P2_CD ...you fill in the rest... P8_CD;

  length DX DY CD 8;

  do seq = 1 to dim(DXs);
    DX = DXs(seq);
    DY = DYs(seq);
    CD = CDs(seq);

    * only output if there is some data;
    if NMISS(DX,DY,CD) < 3 then OUTPUT;
  end;

  * seq is also kept in case you need to know which <#> a DX DY CD came from;
  keep DATE COD TOTAL DX DY CD seq;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Richard, iam gratefull. Great explanation and the solution is spot on.